# undefined method `persisted?' with Reform and Virtus model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reform, trailblazer, virtus

I'm currently developing an Rails app (rails v5.1.1 and ruby v2.3.4) and I'm getting an error when trying to use a [reform](https://github.com/trailblazer/reform) form object at one of my routes (`/bookings/new`):

```ruby
undefined method `persisted?' for #<Booking:0x007fbae9a98138>
```

I'm using a [virtus model](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) (which works fine on other contexts):

```ruby
class Booking
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :id, Integer
  attribute :client_email, String
end
```

This is my form object:

```ruby
class BookingForm < Reform::Form
  property :client_email
end
```

This is the `new` action on my controller:

```ruby
def new
  @form = BookingForm.new(Booking.new)
end
```

This is my form partial:

```ruby
<%= form_for @form do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :client_email %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I thought using a virtus model instead of an active record one should be no issue since reform sells itself as `Form objects decoupled from your models`. Did I get anything wrong?

Comment: you could just define `def persisted?` in your `Booking` class, and use whatever logic you want there, you could just return `false` if the class will only represent new objects.

Comment: This does not seem to be the proper approach since I'd also need to implement a `to_key` method at my Booking model (to return the elements of the form). After that I get the error: `undefined method `input' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x007fbae9e10450>` (at the line of my input).

Comment: there are many things you can use, for instance `ActiveModel::Conversion`(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Conversion.html) gives you the `persisted?` method plus some others. You could also use `ActiveModel::Naming`(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html) in case you need it.

Comment: Oops, I actually made a mistake by using the `form.input` method instead of `form.text_field`. My bad.

But the `ActiveModel::Conversion` inclusion actually solved my issue! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the comment from @fanta helped, but I the long-term answer is that you should avoid using Virtus, especially since you are building a new project. Virtus is no longer supported by it's own team, they moved on to dry-rb ( dry-types and dry-validations)

If you need to mock a model - you can use dry-struct, OpenStruct, etc

Also Reform now has full support for dry-validation and dry-types, and it is going to be the way of the future ( thou AM is going to be supported till version 4) 
Best of luck :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!